# Ant debug error in mupdf configuration

Tags: android, mupdf

I tried to integrate mupdf within my Android application, which is built from Windows. I followed the [mupdf guide](http://www.mupdf.com/docs/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android).

When i am executing the ant debug part it gives me this error:

> C:\pdf3\mupdf-1.6-source\mupdfgit\mupdf\platform\android\build.xml:83:
>   Cannot find C:\Users
>   issLv1\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml imported
>   from
>   C:\pdf3\mupdf-1.6-source\mupdfgit\mupdf\platform\android\build.xml

Why does it search for a build xml file inside the SDK folder?

Comment: All android apps used to be ant builds and inherited from an Android written build.xml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The build.xml file in the Android SDK defines the various standard Ant tasks necessary to build Android applications with Ant.

Is this the correct location for your Android SDK? If not check the setting of the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

Does that file actually exist? If not you maybe your SDK is corrupt and you need to reinstall it.

Comment: I am having the same error and I have build.xml. how do I fix this problem?

Comment: @AndroidNewBee We'd need to see the exact error message you're getting; you shouldn't be getting a 'not found' error if the file exists! It would probably be best to open a new question to cover your situation.